# Git clone set to origin, could not read from remote repository

Tags: git

My colleague pushed to develop. I have a completely different version of the project of my colleague. He has implemented new features, I can see his commit but they are not included in my project at all.
`git fetch remote`

`fatal: 'remote' does not appear to be a git repository`  
`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

So far I have done:

`git clone https://github.com/tihomirtodorov/HotelManagement.git

git checkout -b develop
git fetch remote`

When I use `git remote -v`

it provides me with

`origin  https://github.com/tihomirtodorov/HotelManagement.git (fetch)` 
       `origin  https://github.com/tihomirtodorov/HotelManagement.git (push)`

I have also re-installed git, even downloaded as .zip the develop branch and I cannot get the latest changes he has done.

Please help, the project is due on Monday and I need to write some unit tests.

Comment: `git fetch origin develop` or try `git pull origin develop`, just use the remote´s name (origin) instead of remote

Comment: @john first option gave me  * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD,
second 
Already up to date.

Comment: Then I think u already got the latest version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git fetch remote` means "fetch all updates from the remote repo called `remote`", and you don't have a repo called `remote` configured.

You want to make it just `git fetch`. See `git help fetch` for syntax details.

Comment: I used git fetch, no message appears, then I write git pull Already up to date.

Comment: Yes I understand that but when I get fetch develop I got the please make sure you have correct access rights message.

Comment: `git fetch` doesn't give any message if there is nothing to fetch, that's expected. `git fetch develop` gives the same message about missing repo, because you don't have a remote named `develop`. And you generally don't want to give fetch branch names, you want to fetch everything. if you have branch `develop` in your repo, it should be visible as `origin/develop` in your repo. Did you try asking your colleague for help? They should know best where their changes are.

Answer (score 0):

What we did is we created a branch from develop and I managed to checkout set it as origin and it worked fine.